# How do I display a progress indicator function in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to write a progress indicator function within my script that loops a "please wait" message until the task that called it is done.

I want it to be a function so that I may reuse it in other scripts.

In order to achieve that, the function needs to be loosely coupled with other functions, i.e, the function calling it doesn't have to know its inner code.

Here's what I have so far. This function receives the pid of the caller and loops until the task is finished.

```
function progress() {
  pid="$1"

  kill -n 0 "${pid}" &> /dev/null && echo -ne "please wait"
  while kill -n 0 "${pid}" &> /dev/null ; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
  done
}
```

it works fine when you use it in a script, such as:

```
#imports the shell script with the progress() function
. /path/to/progress.sh

echo "testing"
# $$ returns the pid of the script.
progress $$ &
sleep 5
echo "done"
```

output:

```
$ testing
$ please wait.....
$ done
```

The problem is when I call it from another function, as functions do not have pids:

```
function my_func() {
  progress $$ &
  echo "my func is done"
}

. /path/to/progress.sh
echo "testing"
my_func
sleep 10
echo done
```

output:

```
$ testing
$ please wait.....
$ my func. is done.
$ ..........
$ done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the `dialog` - bash curses oriented menu system.

For the progress bar you can check the http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_progress_bar_(gauge_box)

or, another simpler project:
http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html

if not interested, you can try the next:

```
dotpid=
rundots() { ( trap 'exit 0' SIGUSR1; while : ; do echo -n '.' >&2; sleep 0.2; done) &  dotpid=$!; }
stopdots() { kill -USR1 $dotpid; wait $dotpid; trap EXIT; }
startdots() { rundots; trap "stopdots" EXIT; return 0; }

longproc() {
    echo 'Start doing something long... (5 sec sleep)'
    sleep 5
    echo
    echo 'Finished the long job'
}

run() {
    startdots
    longproc
    stopdots
}

#main
echo start
run
echo doing someting other
sleep 2
echo end of prog
```

Comment: this is close to my previous attempt, but I was trying to avoid having to kill it outside my progress() function... Perhaps it can't be done with a shell script, though. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've tried the code provided, but it suffers from the same problem since SIGTERM is sent when the program is done. I can't use it inside a function unless I explicitly send the kill signal.

Comment: @Tarek don't really understand what do you mean with "inside a function" and "unless send the kill"... but: I edited the script showing how use it within a function, and for the second, of course you __need__ send a signal - somewhat you must tell to the background process: "stop now"... . If you mean something other - can't help...

Comment: Thanks! the code works. I was trying to use a single function to do this, and didn't even consider using more than one! Great idea.

Answer (score 1):

By running it in background you get it's output mixed with the rest of the code, so you must not output anything elsewhere while the `progress` is running.

To implement it as function, you would need a global variable to controll when the progress should terminate (you can pass the name of the variable as arg to the `progress` when calling it).

Comment: thanks, but a global variable wouldn't work, as it wouldn't change inside the function.

Comment: yes it would. That's how shell scripting works. Functions doesn't have return values, you have to use global variables for that too.

Comment: are you talking about exporting the variable? Because I made a quick test  yesterday:
param="test"

function test() {
  echo $1
  sleep 5
  echo $1
 echo ${param}
}

test ${param} &
param="changed"
wait $1
echo ${param}

the output is:
$ test
$ test
$ test
$ changed
 perhaps I misunderstood what you meant with global variable.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong and I'm not gonna read unformatted code like this.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at https://github.com/tokiclover/mkinitramfs-ll/issues/23 it describes a caveat with using variables like that and in the code it references you can see how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about this [project](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html). I haven't used it so not sure how easy it is to integrate, but you can give it a read.

Comment: thanks! I don't need anything that advanced though (just a "please wait..." while the program is executing). I'm going to take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I wasn't able to do what I wanted using shell script. Here's what I've done:

```
function progress() {
  echo -ne "please wait"
  while :
  do
    echo -n '.'
    sleep 1
  done
}
```

usage:

```
aguarde &
dotpid=$!
# code
eval "kill ${dotpid}"
```